# Writing into new email: change the Date -1 if Date = vbMonday to "text"

Tags: vba, outlook

I have developed the code which allows me to send an email with predefined text, which I set to change only where the date is `Date -1`

I need to add another functionality: If the current day is `vbMonday` insert "weekend" instead of `Date - 1`

I was thinking about something along the lines of: `If Date = vbMonday then instead of Date - 1 enter "weekend"`

This is the part:

```
Sub Email_Outlook()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strbody = "Hi," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "No events: " & Date - 1 & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Thanks" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Thomas"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
strbody = "Hi," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "No events: " & IIf(Weekday(Date) = vbMonday, "weekend", Date - 1) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "Thanks" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "Thomas"
```

Comment: Splendid, thank you. I thought it was the easiest [best] way of approaching it. I tried with "If" but it didn't work, can you advise why it is "IIf" and not "If" ? Thanks again

Comment: IIf() function is sort of a shortened version of If-Then-Else construct, the most relevant difference from this latter being that it evaluates both conditions so that if one of them errors then the function does, too. But in this case it’s safe.

Comment: Much Obliged. Regards

Answer (score 1):

Try like this with the weekdays:

```
Public Sub TestMe()    
    If Weekday(Date) = vbWednesday Then
        Debug.Print "It is Wednesday!"
    End If    
End Sub
```